# Isabelle auto prover works on lemma, hangs on special case of the lemma

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

Why does the second lemma's "auto" proving hangs? The second lemma is a special case of the first one.

```
  primrec ListSumTAux :: "nat list ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
    "ListSumTAux []     n = n" |
    "ListSumTAux (x#xs) n = ListSumTAux xs (n+x)" 

  lemma ListSumTAux_1 : " ∀a b. ListSumTAux xs (a+b) = a + ListSumTAux xs b"
    apply (induct xs)
    apply (auto)       (* Works fine *)
  done  

  lemma ListSumTAux_2 : "∀ a. ListSumTAux xs a = a + ListSumTAux xs 0 "  
    apply (induct xs)
    apply (auto)       (* Hangs on this *)
  oops
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: it is inconvenient to state goals with the HOL universal quantifier `∀`. Free variables in goals are implicitly universally quantified anyway, so you can simply leave out the `∀`. You will, however, tell the `induction` command to universally quantify these variables in the induction step using `arbitrary`:

```
lemma ListSumTAux_1 : "ListSumTAux xs (a+b) = a + ListSumTAux xs b"
  apply (induct xs arbitrary: a b)
  apply (auto)
done
```

Now, to answer your question: `auto` gets stuck because your induction hypothesis has the form

```
⋀a. ListSumTAux xs a = a + ListSumTAux xs 0
```

`auto` uses Isabelle's simplifier, which takes this as a rewrite rule. However, you will notice that the left-hand side of this rule matches the right-hande side of this loop, which leads to the infinite rewrite sequence

```
ListSumTAux xs a → a + ListSumTAux xs 0 → a + (0 + ListSumTAux xs 0) → 
    a + (0 + (0 + ListSumTAux xs 0))
```

When these situations occur, there are several things you can do:

1. you can do a structured Isar proof and do things by hand
2. you can try to flip the equation in question, i.e. write the goal as `a + ListSumTAux xs 0 = ListSumTAux xs a`. Then the left-hand side does not match the right-hand side anymore.
3. you can introduce an additional premise like `a ≠ 0` to the equation that prevents the simplifier from looping.

In any case, you will not be able to prove your goal this way, because it is too specific: if you state your goal as `ListSumTAux xs a = a + ListSumTAux xs 0`, then you will have a `0` in the induction hypothesis as well, but of course, your accumulator will not always be `0`.

It is a frequent problem in inductive proofs, especially when accumulators are involved, that you need to generalise your statement in order to strengthen the induction hypothesis before the proof works – like you did in the first statement of the lemma, `ListSumTAux_1`.